# String values not converting to numeric values with replace() method

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am using `.replace()` to replace string values with numeric values for analysis. I am getting no errors, but when I inspect the dataframe afterwards the values remain unchanged. I have also tried using `regex=True` and have had the same problem. Any help is much appreciated. A print screen of my notebook is attached below and raw code is as follows.

```
df['international plan'].replace(['no', 'yes'], [0, 1], inplace = True)

df['voice mail plan'].replace(['yes', 'no'], [1,0], inplace = True)

df['churn'].replace(['False', 'True'], [0, 1], inplace = True)
```

[Print screen from my Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tyby.png)

Micah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem some white spaces in values:

```
np.random.seed(789)
df = pd.DataFrame({'international plan': np.random.choice([' yes',' no'], size=5),
                  'voice mail plan': np.random.choice([' yes',' no'], size=5),
                  'churn': np.random.choice([' False.',' True.'], size=5),
                  'area code': np.random.choice([415,408], size=5)})
print (df)
   area code    churn international plan voice mail plan
0        408    True.                 no             yes
1        415   False.                yes             yes
2        408    True.                yes              no
3        408   False.                yes             yes
4        408   False.                 no             yes
```

Solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for loop columns `cols` and use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dict`:

```
cols = ['international plan','voice mail plan','churn']
d = {'no':0,'yes':1, 'True.':1, 'False.':0}
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip().replace(d))
print (df)
   area code  churn  international plan  voice mail plan
0        408      1                   0                1
1        415      0                   1                1
2        408      1                   1                0
3        408      0                   1                1
4        408      0                   0                1
```

Or add whitespaces to keys in `dict`, then use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
cols = ['international plan','voice mail plan','churn']
d = {' no':0,' yes':1, ' True.':1, ' False.':0}
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(d)
```

And if want to replace each column separately:

```
df['international plan'] = df['international plan'].str.strip().replace(['no','yes'],[0, 1])
df['voice mail plan'] = df['voice mail plan'].str.strip().replace(['yes','no'],[1,0])
df['churn'] = df['churn'].str.strip().replace(['False.','True.'],[0, 1])
print (df)
   area code  churn  international plan  voice mail plan
0        408      1                   0                1
1        415      0                   1                1
2        408      1                   1                0
3        408      0                   1                1
4        408      0                   0                1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

as per your Notebook screenshot, your column values 'yes', 'no', 'True.', and 'False.' contains spaces around it, hence the .replace() is not working, strip the spaces and change yes/no to 1/0, like:

```
df['international plan'] = df['international plan'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.strip() == "yes" else 0)

df['voice mail plan'] = df['voice mail plan'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.strip() == "yes" else 0)

df['churn'] = df['churn'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.strip() == "True." else 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!